# 'electron' is not recognized as an internal or external command when using nodemon

Tags: electron

I have the following scripts in my electron js app's package.json

```
"start": "electron .",
"dev": "nodemon --exec electron ."
```

butI get the following error when I run the app as `npm run dev`

```
'electron' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file
```

and the app crashes. However, when I run it as `npm start` it runs fine with no issues.

What maybe the issue with nodemon?

Answer (score 2):

You can resolve it by executing electron with npx:

```
"dev": "nodemon --exec npx electron ."
```

but this will run a new instance every time you make a change.

Alternatively, you can install electron globally:

```
npm i -g electron
```

Answer (score 1):

I've got the same problem and than I noticed that I didn't install npm using

```
npm install
```

in the same directory and `node_modules` folder was missing.